# Cannot import nodebox.graphics on Python

Tags: python, graphics, nodebox

I'm trying to use [NodeBox for OpenGL](http://www.cityinabottle.org/nodebox/) with Python, but I'm being unable to import the library on both Python 2 and 3.

```
espaco@Arch ~> python2
Python 2.7.11 (default, Dec  6 2015, 15:43:46) 
[GCC 5.2.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from nodebox.graphics import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nodebox_opengl-1.6-py2.7.egg/nodebox/graphics/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import bezier
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nodebox_opengl-1.6-py2.7.egg/nodebox/graphics/bezier.py", line 10, in <module>
    from context import BezierPath, PathElement, PathError, Point, MOVETO, LINETO, CURVETO, CLOSE
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nodebox_opengl-1.6-py2.7.egg/nodebox/graphics/context.py", line 29, in <module>
    import geometry
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nodebox_opengl-1.6-py2.7.egg/nodebox/graphics/geometry.py", line 454, in <module>
    from pyglet.gl import \
ImportError: cannot import name pointer
>>>
```

---

```
espaco@Arch ~> python3
Python 3.5.1 (default, Dec  7 2015, 12:58:09) 
[GCC 5.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from nodebox.graphics import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nodebox_opengl-1.6-py3.5.egg/nodebox/graphics/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'bezier'
>>>
```

I don't have a clue on the Python 2 error, but the Python 3 one seems nonsensical to me since if I do a `tree` on the library directory **I can see `bezier.py` in there** as such:

```
espaco@Arch ~> tree /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nodebox/
/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nodebox/
├── ext
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── psyco
│   │   ├── classes.py
│   │   ├── core.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── kdictproxy.py
│   │   ├── logger.py
│   │   ├── profiler.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   ├── classes.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   │   └── logger.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   └── support.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   └── setup.cpython-35.pyc
│   └── setup.py
├── graphics
│   ├── bezier.py
│   ├── context.py
│   ├── geometry.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── noise.py
│   ├── physics.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   └── noise.cpython-35.pyc
│   └── shader.py
├── gui
│   ├── controls.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __pycache__
│       └── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
├── __init__.py
├── __pycache__
│   └── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
└── sound
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── osc.py
    ├── process.py
    └── __pycache__
        └── __init__.cpython-35.pyc

11 directories, 31 files
```

Why am I getting these errors? How may I fix them?

Comment: https://github.com/nodebox/nodebox-opengl/issues/8

Answer (score 0):

Try [nodebox-opengl 1.6.1](https://pypi.org/project/nodebox-opengl/) + pyglet-1.3.3